# Is there a way to force R into placing the decimal at the pipe in a stem and leaf plot?

Tags: r

Let's assume the data is:

```
y=rpois(100,50)
z=rpois(50,500)
x=rpois(5,1000)
v=c(y,z,x)
```

When I do `stem(v)` it places the decimal two places to the right of the |.  I have tried using `scale` and `width` but cannot seem to be able to force the decimal at the |.  Is there a way to do this?  If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, no, because your data is between 31 and 1021 (for my random numbers). The idea of stem is to try and show as many of your data points as possible. If the decimal was at the bar then that wouldn't leave anything to the right of the bar, since you've got whole numbers...

```
stem(v/100)
```

does what you say, but I'm not sure its what you want...

Comment: Sorry, I meant one to the right; in any case `stem(v/10)` will return the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hack. It works by (1) capturing the output of `stem`, (2) placing the decimal two digits to the right of `|` and (3) writing the lines back to the console.

```
stem_with_dot <- function(x, ...){
   h = capture.output(stem(x, ...))
   stem_plot = sub("\\| ([0-9]{2})", "| \\1.", h)
   writeLines(stem_plot)
   return(invisible)
}
```